# Using Ruby Curb gem with API token

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, curb

Brand new to Ruby. I'm referencing the Curb documentation and attempting to submit a request in curl that utilizes a security token. Here are the 3 parts to my header with my traditional request:

1. My-Security-Token
2. 1234567890
3. website.com

How would I structure Curb to submit Name, Value and Comment as seen above?

What I'm starting with:

```
c = Curl::Easy.new("http://website.com") do |curl| 
  curl.headers["Name"] = "My-Security-Token"
  curl.headers["Value"] = "1234567890"
  curl.headers["Comment"] = "website.com"
  curl.verbose = true
end

c.perform
```

Comment: so what really is your question?

Comment: As Jasdeep Singh hinted at, you need to post what your actual results are and what your expected results are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Here are the 3 parts to my header with my traditional request
>
> 1. My-Security-Token
> 2. 1234567890
> 3. website.com

Headers consist of name/value *pairs*, so your description doesn't make any sense.

It looks your header name should be:

```
 My-Security-Token
```

and it's value should be:

```
 1234567890
```

To make a `GET request` (you didn't mention what type of request you are making) and specify that header, you can do this:

```
require 'curb'

http = Curl.get("http://website.com/") do |http| 
  http.headers["My-Security-Token"] = "1234567890"
end

puts http.body_str[0..249]  #Output the first 250 characters of the response
```

If you want to use verbose mode, which will display the actual request and response, you can do this:

```
require 'curb'

c = Curl::Easy.new("http://www.google.com/") do |curl| 
  curl.headers["My-Security-Token"] = "1234567890"
  curl.verbose = true
end

c.perform  #Outputs the request and the response
puts c.body_str[0..249]  #body_str => the body of the response
```

output:

```
* About to connect() to www.google.com port 80 (#0)
*   Trying 74.125.28.147... * Connected to www.google.com (74.125.28.147) port 80 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: www.google.com
Accept: */*
My-Security-Token: 1234567890  #***HERE IS YOUR CUSTOM HEADER****

< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Date: Tue, 03 Mar 2015 00:14:42 GMT
< Expires: -1
< Cache-Control: private, max-age=0
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1
< Set-Cookie: PREF=ID=479a8fa626097193:FF=0:TM=1425341682:LM=1425341682:S=5kflGPOAzEx-uMWb; expires=Thu, 02-Mar-2017 00:14:42 GMT; path=/; domain=.google.com
< Set-Cookie: NID=67=Eim3D__PFGbpSWdcIH9IPhkuDEVMFjN4ShU9gA6Z_rMryMoI6nv--sIjk_E00_EpMfSe3RkPO5dYjV7yGTXT3oMLX-t7FsrKSJmF7-OffAuLKrr5KfV1IZzL9yaJQKiB; expires=Wed, 02-Sep-2015 00:14:42 GMT; path=/; domain=.google.com; HttpOnly
< P3P: CP="This is not a P3P policy! See http://www.google.com/support/accounts/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=151657 for more info."
< Server: gws
< X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
< X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
< Alternate-Protocol: 80:quic,p=0.08
< Accept-Ranges: none
< Vary: Accept-Encoding
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
< 
* Expire cleared
* Connection #0 to host www.google.com left intact
<!doctype html><html itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/WebPage" lang="en"><head><meta content="Search the world's information, including webpages, images, videos and more. Google has many specia
```

If you actually want the custom headers to be:

```
Name: My-Security-Token
Value: 1234567890
Comment: website.com
```

...then you can do this:

```
require 'curb'

c = Curl::Easy.new("http://www.google.com/") do |curl| 
  curl.headers["Name"] = "My-Security-Token"
  curl.headers["Value"] = "1234567890"
  curl.headers["Comment"] = "website.com"
  curl.verbose = true
end

c.perform
puts c.body_str[0..249]
```

...which will produce output like this:

```
* About to connect() to www.google.com port 80 (#0)
*   Trying 74.125.28.105... * Connected to www.google.com (74.125.28.105) port 80 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: www.google.com
Accept: */*
Name: My-Security-Token   #HERE ARE YOUR HEADERS
Value: 1234567890         #HERE
Comment: website.com      #HERE
...
...
```

If nothing above does what you want, then instead of describing your request, how about posting your *actual* "traditional" request?  If you don't know how to do that, search google.

Answer (score 0):

> How would I structure Curb to submit Name, Value and Comment as seen above?

On second thought, it looks like Name, Value, and Comment are the components of a single http header:

> Comments can be included in some HTTP header fields by surrounding
>   the comment text with parentheses. Comments are only allowed in
>   fields containing "comment" as part of their field value definition.
>   In all other fields, parentheses are considered part of the field
>   value.

If that's the case, you can create your custom header like this:

```
require 'curb'

c = Curl::Easy.new("http://www.google.com/") do |curl| 
  curl.headers["My-Security-Token"] = "1234567890 (website.com)"
  curl.verbose = true
end

c.perform  #Outputs the request and the response
puts c.body_str[0..249]  #body_str => the body of the response

--output:--
* About to connect() to www.google.com port 80 (#0)
*   Trying 74.125.28.104... * Connected to www.google.com (74.125.28.104) port 80 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: www.google.com
Accept: */*
My-Security-Token: 1234567890 (website.com)  #***YOUR CUSTOM HEADER****
...
...
```